# What's the equation for $\mathbb{E}(XY)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, discrete random variables. Suppose I want to find $\mathbb{E}(XY)$. What's the equation for it? My educated guess is that the equation for the expected value in this case is

$$ \sum_x\sum_yxyP(X = x)P(Y = y) $$

And you sum over the $x$ and $y$ values over which both $X$ and $Y$ take positive probabilities, i.e. you sum over the intersection of the support of $X$ and $Y$.

I haven't found the equation for this case in any of the three textbooks I checked, and I don't want to rely on some educated guess in case I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ in my upcoming exam.

Thanks.

Comment: In *three textbooks* they do not mention that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent? That is unbelievable.

Comment: First one is a very introductory book so I understand that. Second book was Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross. Maybe it's there, but it's not noticeable. Third book was Casella's Statistical Inference, 2nd edition. Casella's book is advanced so I'm sure the formula is there, but it's not a very well organized book.

Comment: Next time, you might want to google "expected value of product"...

Answer (score 5):

Your formula for $EXY$ is correct and we also have $EXY=(EX)(EY)=(\sum xP(X=x))(\sum yP(Y=y))$.

Comment: That makes computations much easier. Thanks.